# Can't generate APK in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have an android application ready to release. I'm trying to generate the APK in the android studio in the section 'build apk'. I'm using some externals libraries. However, I'm getting errors related to bytecode to dex. I already search for solutions, but no success.

This is the errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/loopj/android/http/BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/loopj/android/http/BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/loopj/android/http/BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler;
```

And this is `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.NanoStima.AndroidClient"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

 dependencies {
    //   compile 'com.github.scribejava:scribejava-apis:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    compile group: 'org.mindrot', name: 'jbcrypt', version: '0.3m'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
}
```

Can anyone help?

WARNING NEW: I was testing some of your sugestions and the project just dont run anymore. I made a reroll for the initial gradle, and still have this error :
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I already clean the project, delete .gradle, restart android studio. Just dont run anymore :\

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: @Sudakatux Im using the embeded JDK, and the SDK provided by android studio. Last version i guess, i just reinstall the studio one week a go to try resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly get there. I reverse gradle from last version to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you use the full google play services library in your dependencies and I suspect its the root cause of the bytecode to dex problem. Instead of using the whole library you should try using only the specific ones you need. e.g.

instead of:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0
```

you could use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
```

or consider using multi dex. ref:[Android multi-dex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Whith that step, it launches an error ' Unable to merge dex' when run.
Im already using multi-dex- as it is present im my gradle.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error messages you will see that the problem is caused by:

compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'

In your build.gradle (project level) add this :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}
```

And your problem will probably be resolved (in this case by jcenter()).

Notice:

It is google() or maven {url 'https://maven.google.com'} depends on your Gradle version. If you have Gradle version 4.1 then you use google(), in the other case the maven part.

You can find some more explanation here [Remote repositories](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

Comment: Also Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex